How do I switch between multiple browser windows or tabs in Selenium with Java?
I am working with multiple tabs in a browser, but I can’t figure out how to switch from one window/tab to another. How can I correctly handle switching between multiple windows in Selenium WebDriver?
String originalWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.id("openNewTab")).click();

    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String windowHandle : windowHandles) {

    if (!windowHandle.equals(originalWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
     }
    }


Can you say what is wrong here? Do you have multiple window handles after "clicking" openNewTab?

When working with multiple windows in Selenium WebDriver, here’s how you can handle them step by step:

First, save the original window’s handle using getWindowHandle(). This is important so you can switch back to it later.
After opening a new window (like by clicking a button that opens a new tab), use getWindowHandles() to get all the currently open window handles.
Then, use switchTo().window() to switch to the new window.

Here’s a simple example of how the code looks:
//Save the original window handle

String originalWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();


// Open a new window (e.g., by clicking a button)

driver.findElement(By.id("openNewTab")).click();


// Get all window handles

Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();


// Switch to the new window


for (String windowHandle : windowHandles) {


    if (!windowHandle.equals(originalWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);


        break;
    }
}

// Once done with the new window, you can switch back to the original window

driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);


Hi Nadia. Did you generate this answer using an AI assistant such as ChatGPT?
